# spring boot tomcat server output stuck on exception message

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

So I have a Spring Boot 'Web' REST server. 
In my controller class (where I define the endpoints) I have a method fetch(int page, int size) that fetches a List.

I have instantiated an arraylist of size 1000 to demonstrate, and all is well and good so long as I fetch() with page and size that is with the arraylist bound (quick example fetch(0,10) -> now I have a List with 10 Stuff objects (with id's 0 thru 9)).....HOWEVER,
when I make a call to the server "localhost:8080/fetch?page=10&size=500" the output dialog in my cygwin terminal says something about an exception limit out of bounds or something...

which is probably expected, but the server is still 'up' and functioning, as in I can make subsequent calls and still get responses... but the server output dialog in cygwin is still 'stuck' on the exception message, and now the new requests don't give the usual "responded in 15ms".....  my question is will throwing/catching that exception in the controller/service class allow the cygwin output of the program to remain in sync or is there logging level stuff I should check next? tytytyty

Comment: *"server output dialog in cygwin"*? What does cygwin have to do with this. How are you displaying output? We don't have enough information about what you're actually doing, to help figure out why output is stuck.

Comment: Please provide some code to demonstrate where the issue might be, see [mcve].